# using smart pointers with "this"

Tags: c++, boost, boost-smart-ptr

I'm learning the use of boost smart pointers but I'm a bit confused about a few situations.
Let's say I'm implementing a state machine where each state is implemented by a single update method. 
Each state could return itself or create a new state object:

```
struct state
{
    virtual state* update() = 0;  // The point: I want to return a smart pointer here
};

struct stateA : public state
{
    virtual state* update() { return this; }
};

struct stateB : public state
{
    virtual state* update() { if(some condition) return new stateA() else return this; }
```

};

The state machine loop would look like this:

```
while(true)
    current_state = current_state->update();
```

Could you translate this code to use boost smart pointers? I'm a bit confused when it comes to the "return this" part because I don't know what to do.
Basically I think it's useless to return something like "return boost::shared_ptr(this);" because it's not safe.
What should I do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may want to look at [`enable_shared_from_this`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.html), which is there for specificly solving problems similar to yours.

Answer (score 6):

You have to make your classes inherit from `boost::enable_shared_from_this<>`.  Check out Boost's example [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.html).